# executing arbitrary code at Julia breakpoint

Tags: debugging, julia, breakpoints

I have the following Julia code in a file `test_debug.jl`

```
using Debugger

function main()
    x = 1 + 2
    @bp
    println("Exiting function main...$(x)");
end
```

At the command line I say

```
include("test_debug.jl")
@run main()
```

Now how can I execute arbitrary Julia code at the breakpoint, like I can do with Python's `breakpoint()` function?

I would very much like  to just say

```
print(x)
```

At the debugger prompt. And execute other Julia code as well. Is this possible?  Executing `print(x)` at the debugger prompt gives

```
Unknown command print(x). Run ? to obtain help.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [README](https://github.com/JuliaDebug/Debugger.jl/blob/master/README.md#debugger-commands) you can find either the `w` command to add variables to a watch list, or for arbitrary expressions you can type a backtick, `, to enter evaluation mode where you can execute code in the current debug context.